# Linux create a new user that shares everything of another user

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, user-accounts, redhat-enterprise-linux

A little background first, since I know this question seems very random.

I am using vagrant to help orchestrate a RedHat virtual machine. Vagrant is great in just about every way, however it forces the creation of a user `vagrant`. This is normally fine, but in the end, I plan to create a separate user name named `bill`.

What I'd like to have happen is both the user `vagrant` is created, but the user `bill` is an equivalent account. It can share the same home directory via a symlink, but most importantly, file permissions of `vagrant:vagrant` would be exactly the same as `bill`.

I'm finding it hard to google this strange request and didn't find much.

Any advice on how to thoroughly perform an operation like this?

Comment: [Possible approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124968/108618).

Comment: Have you tried add user `bill` to the group `vagrant`?